# Windows 10 won't remember RDP credentials anymore

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

I've got a question for you guys, I hope that you can help me. The question is simple, I don't know about the solution...

The thing is I usually work with a made .rdp file that allows me to connect to a remote desktop session out of the box; the first time you executed it it just asked you the credentials and you were allowed to save them, so that it won't ask you again, as seen in this pic:

[image]

I've never had problems with this, but lately (I think it happened since some Windows 10 update) it's always asking me the credentials and doesn't show the previous checkbox to remember them.

So the question is simple: How can I do (the simplest possible way) to make it ask me again wether I want to save them?

I tried some solutions like changing some values in gpedit.msc , at: Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Temples > System > Credentials Delegation ; and it works, but I would need a simpler solution (if possible) that just brings me back the checkbox.

I also confirmed already that it's caused by an update, cause I found [this thread](https://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/par_clientsol/forum/par_win/windows-10-1703-unable-to-connect-via-remote/1e9cec01-38d2-44ab-95ab-b1128964ccf4) at the official Microsoft forum which talks precisely about the same problem, and after the update my computer also couldn't connect to that remote desktop session anymore because of a transport layer error (which I solved already by clearing the credentials from the Windows credentials manager, as mentioned in that thread). Then after that, I found the issue why I'm opening this post and the one that is discussed in the previous link too. They talk about a workaround by changing some .dll and .exe , but I need a simpler solution to tell the people I'm working with having same issue. I updated already to the latest available update (including KB4025342 that supposedly solves it) but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it with one of the next choices, its up to you which one to use:

1) Start -> Run -> `control userpasswords2` press enter.
then go to Advanced tab and see Passwords Manager, or something like this, and just delete your old password from there from that resource. Therefore at the next time it will ask you again for new password.

2) Start -> Configuration - Control Panel - Users and Passwords. And the go to Password manager.

3) in the cmd ( Start - Run. and type there "cmd" without quotes ofcourse and press enter. in the cmd type:

```
net use * /del
```

and press enter

In the last versions of Windows, passwords stores not in rdp-file, rather than in Credential Manager.
To be able to save the password you need to enable the following:
start and enter `gpedit.msc`
Navigate to here: `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Credentials Delegation`
from the right side choose `Allow Saved Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication` and push `enable` and add the name of remote computer in format `TERMSRV/<computername>` push `OK` and try to connect to remote computer/server with saving the password
p.s. You can set `*` instead of `<computername>`  than you will be able to save password for all servers.

dont forget to do

```
gpupdate /force
```

before try to connect

Comment: Thanks for your comment Vladimir! But the problem isn't that I want to clear the password (in fact I did that already as I said).. what I want is right the opposite, that the connection dialog allows me to remember it again as it did previously through the checkbox "Remember my password". Since some Windows 10 update that checkbox isn't present anymore.

Comment: is this computer in Domain? or Workgroup?

Comment: It's in Domain, but the rdp connection is over the Internet, it doesn't depend on that... In fact it seems to be a generalized issue according to the link that I attached from the Microsoft forum.

Comment: than try my last paragraph. please refresh the page, i;ve edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for the info, yeah I did that already as I wrote in the description, and sure it works, but I would need a simpler method... Do you think it's not possible? Or could I do a .bat file that enables the configuration you mentioned?

Comment: Note that with option 1) you can manually add the credential you want saved. This was what it took for RDP to automatically log in for me.

Answer (score -2):

The issue I found with this solution is that is uses authentication of the current user for RDP connections. If you have to use other credentials for the RDP session, you are out of luck!

Comment: By default RDP will use the current user. You can use alternate credentials just fine, and I have for the last 5 years. This is not correct.